# Returning provider throws error on Main.dart page

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, chopper

I am using chopper following a youtube tutorial, I have never used provider before and when I do the following I get errors. If I don't use the provider I get errors on the app screen of no provider found.

#### I get errors on the return provider line and builder line

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:relationship/screens/weekly_view.dart';
import 'package:relationship/services/chopper_services.dart';

void main() => MyApp();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
        builder: (_) => PersonalPostingService.create(),
        dispose: (context, PersonalPostingService service) =>
            service.client.dispose(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: WeeklyData(),
        ));
  }
}
```

#### These are the errors

```
The named parameter 'create' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.

The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget?)?'.

The return type 'PersonalPostingService' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.
```

#### I am using chopper API but it doesn't throw any errors. I have local notifications code but I have commented it from the main.dart file

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Provider widget, one of the required parameters used to be `builder`, which would take a function to create the provided class, the parameter has since been renamed to `create`, so replacing the word `builder` with `create` should do the trick, either that or downgrading your provider version into the same version used in the tutorial.

```
return Provider(
        create: (_) => PersonalPostingService.create(),
        dispose: (context, PersonalPostingService service) =>
            service.client.dispose(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: WeeklyData(),
        ));
```

I also recommend going into the changelog of the provider package, you can find it on pub.dev, it should show every change between the tutorial's version and your current one. That way, if something else breaks, you can go there and check if there are any breaking changes that could have caused it.

Comment: now I don't get an error I get a blank screen